# ESP32-C3 JTAG/USB debugging issue with ESP-IDF

Tags: esp32, debugging, jtag

I am using ESP32-C3 module and I want to debug my code through USB/JTAG.

For USB interface I have used TYPE C connector with ESP32-C3.

Connections are as follow but the device does not get recognized:

TYPE C <-----> ESP32-C3,
D- (A7) <-----> GPIO 18,
D+ (A6) <-----> GPIO 19,
V_BUS (B9) <-----> 5V,
GND (B1) <-----> GND

Other thing I tried was debugging through JTAG.

For Jtag degugging as external one we need to strap pin GPIO10 which is not at all a strapping pin in documentation.
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp ... /gpio.html

C:\Users\User_name\esp\esp-idf\components\esptool_py\esptool>espefuse.py -p COM11 burn_efuse JTAG_SEL_ENABLE
I used this command for burning fuse but says invalid efuse name

[image: JTAG OUTPUT]

[image: Connections]

Thanks for help in advance !!!

Comment: Which port you use at the computer end, do you use USB-C?

Comment: what is in that black rectangle at the top?

Comment: @Justme yes i have used USB-C

Comment: @jsotola it is the output for JTAG debugging while burning a efuse to enable JTAB

Comment: it is difficult to see ..  please do not post screenshots of text ... add the text itself

Answer (score 1):

You have a USB-C connector breakout board. You are only connecting to the familiar USB-A pins, which is not enough. A device with USB-C connector must connect resistors to the CC pins to signal to the host that something is connected and what it is.

If memory serves, you need to pull both CC pins down to GND with 5.1 kohm resistors for the PC to know that there is a USB legacy device connected.